# Different color of every single bar of seaborn bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a very wide range of data that I plot using seaborn bar plot. As I use hue, the two different colors are the same for all the data, but I want that every single bar is a different color.

#This is the colors I want for every bar:
palette = ["#fee090","#fdae61","#4575b4","#313695","#e0f3f8","#abd9e9","#d73027", "#a50026"]

ax3=sns.barplot(data=Results,x="Mineral ", y="FLT",hue="Media size ",palette=palette,ci=None, ecolor='black',edgecolor='black',)

#this is my data frame

| Media size | Material bead | Mineral | FLT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.70 | MinFree | 0.00 | 14.86 |
| 1.70 | MinFree | 0.00 | 14.34 |
| 3.00 | MinFree | 0.00 | 9.95 |
| 3.00 | MinFree | 0.00 | 9.68 |
| 1.70 | GIC | 4.00 | 14.87 |
| 1.70 | GIC | 4.00 | 14.38 |
| 3.00 | GIC | 4.00 | 11.80 |
| 3.00 | GIC | 4.00 | 11.12 |
| 1.70 | IC60 | 4.00 | 11.80 |
| 1.70 | IC60 | 4.00 | 11.12 |
| 3.00 | IC60 | 4.00 | 9.24 |
| 3.00 | IC60 | 4.00 | 8.99 |
| 1.70 | BHX | 4.00 | 9.85 |
| 1.70 | BHX | 4.00 | 9.70 |
| 3.00 | BHX | 4.00 | 7.17 |
| 3.00 | BHX | 4.00 | 6.70 |

#This is the result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYVOn.png) and as you can see it just takes the two first values of the pallette.

Another doubt. When I run the ci=69 for standard error, the error bars that I obtain are not correct. In some bars are mising, it makes somehting weird. Any hint on this?

THANKS

Comment: There are only two different `Media size`s (`1.70` and `3.00`), so only two colors.  You could try `hue='Mineral', dodge=False` to change the color depending on its x value.

Comment: The latest seaborn version doesn't support `ci=...` anymore, it uses `errorbar=('ci', ...)` instead.  Do you have reproducible data and code that show your problem?

Comment: I am working with the errorbars, and I think I have the code. I just need to do some changes, and it should work! Thank you veyr much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `hue`, seaborn assigns one color per hue value. In this case there seem to be two hue values (`1.70` and `3.00`), so two colors are used.

To give each bar a separate color, you could iterate through the generated bars and manually assign the colors.  Note that for each `hue` value, a `container` is created for the bars with that `hue`.

You can use the `HandlerTuple` legend handler to show all color in the legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

palette = ["#fee090", "#fdae61", "#4575b4", "#313695", "#e0f3f8", "#abd9e9", "#d73027", "#a50026"]

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617540')[0]

ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='Material bead', y='FLT', hue='Media size', palette=palette, errorbar=None,
                 edgecolor='black')  ###errorbar=('ci', 69))
for bars, colors in zip(ax.containers, (palette[0::2], palette[1::2])):
     for bar, color in zip(bars, colors):
          bar.set_facecolor(color)
ax.legend(handles=[tuple(bar_group) for bar_group in ax.containers],
          labels=[bar_group.get_label() for bar_group in ax.containers],
          title=ax.legend_.get_title().get_text(),
          handlelength=4, handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0.1)})
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with hue and individual bar colors]

If you want to color the bars and hatch one of the hues with a pattern, you can call `set_hatch()` on those bars.  You could update the legend already created by seaborn to indicate the hatching on a grey background. (Creating a new legend, as in the previous example, would also work here. But note that hatching is not so easy to see in small areas.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617540')[0]

ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='Material bead', y='FLT', hue='Media size', palette=['lightgrey', 'lightgrey'],
                 errorbar=None, edgecolor='black')
palette = ["#fee090", "#4575b4", "#e0f3f8", "#d73027"]
for bars, hatch, legend_handle in zip(ax.containers, ['', '//'], ax.legend_.legendHandles):
     for bar, color in zip(bars, palette):
          bar.set_facecolor(color)
          bar.set_hatch(hatch)
     # update the existing legend, use twice the hatching pattern to make it denser
     legend_handle.set_hatch(hatch + hatch)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn hatched bars]

Comment: That is very helpful indeed! Also, if in case I want to do the 3.0 mm stripped instead of a dark color, I guess it is the same sequence, isnt it? Thank you very much

Comment: Its easier to loop through `ax.containers` instead of `ax.patches`.  Anyway, you"ll first get all the 1.7 mm bars and then all the 3 mm bars.

Comment: I have changed and added some hatches to the graph. So now, the 3.0 is with hatches. but I want the legend to be white
(because there are for colors) so have the legend white with nothing for 1.70 (with edgecolor black) and then 
hacing white with \\\\ for 3.0. But when I put white everything cancels (the edgecolor and the hatches)
If I add this to the code it is good, but it is in orange...Any tip?
              w= mpatches.Patch(hatch='', edgecolor='black',label='1.7')
w2 = mpatches.Patch( hatch='\\\\',edgecolor='black',label='3.0')
plt.legend(handles=[w,w2],bbox_to_anchor=(1.3,1.05))

Comment: That is great! and a good solution!! Thank you very very muuuuch!

Comment: I thought that `pd.read_html` was very cool but sadly it gives a 403. Maybe they banned crawlers.

Comment: @julaine The error depends on how things are installed. See e.g. [HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when reading HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590153) or [Pandas pd.read_html Gives me 'HTTP Error 403:'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150272) for some workaround.

Comment: @JohanC that's just pretending to be a browser so SO doesn't realize you are scraping.

Comment: How to keep the legend with both information of colors and texture? E.g.: category_xaxis ref to colors and media_size ref to texture.

Comment: @YuriSantos The legend of the colors is already in the x-axis. If you also put it the legend, the plot gets cluttered by unnecessary information. If you have a special situation, you might want to create a new question.