# Setting grouped barplot colour based on the catagory and not the grouping used with hue in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to change how the colours are displayed when plotting a grouped barplot with seaborn.

In the following minimal example,you get the output you would expect, the colour being set on the group. However, I want the colour to be set based on the category.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1]
group = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
category = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']

data = pd.DataFrame(zip(category, group, data), columns=['category', 'group', 'data'])

palette = sns.color_palette("pastel")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
sns.barplot(data=data, x='category', y='data', palette=palette, hue='group', edgecolor='k', zorder=3, ax=ax)
ax.grid(zorder=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I attempted to use a custom palette where each colour is repeated twice, but it still colours by the group and therefore displays with the same colour for all bars.

```
palette = [color for color in sns.color_palette("pastel") for _ in range(2)]
```

[image]

Is it possible to change the colouring to have the colour set on the category and not the group with Seaborn?

Comment: This functionality isn't present out-of-the-box. What would you put in your legend? Does the casual viewer of your plot need to know which bar belongs to which group?

Comment: See [Different color of every single bar of seaborn bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617540/different-color-of-every-single-bar-of-seaborn-bar-plot) for an example of first drawing the bar plot, and in a second pass recolor each bar. Optionally with hatching or using a different shade of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sns.catplot` and make it look like a `sns.barplot`. As it creates its own new figure, `plt.subplots()` should not be called.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'data': [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1],
                     'group': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                     'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']})

sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid')
g = sns.catplot(data=data, kind='bar', x='group', y='data', col='category', hue='category',
                width=1, palette='pastel', legend=False, aspect=0.3)
sns.despine(left=True, right=True, top=True)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.margins(x=0.1)  # more distance between the categories
    ax.grid(True, axis='y', zorder=0)
    ax.grid(False, axis='x')
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn make catplot look like barplot]